# The function does not run in an external file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I work on a wordpress page, using the google maps api.

my file functions:

```
function liceoucatolica_estilo() {

    // API google maps
    wp_enqueue_script('maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAJq5xO31rYRAqv5h6yUZTOaHwDX2zjNlo&callback=initMap', array(), false);

    // Cargar scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',null,false);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','liceoucatolica_estilo');
```

my file main.js (In which is the function of the map):

```
window.onload = function(){ 

  function initMap(){
  var campus = {lat: 4.634241, lng: -74.068513};

    // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mi_mapa'), {
        center: campus,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 17
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: campus,
        map: map,
        title: 'Liceo de la Universidad Católica'
    }); 
  }

};
```

If I copy the function in the header or footer if it works, but if I only leave it in Main.js does not work

Answer (score 0):

There can be two causes:

1.- You're declaring the function when the window.onload event has already happened, so it keeps listening for something that will never happen.

2.- Google maps's script resolves before you get the chance to declare function `initMap`.

I'd try switching the order of the scripts, and removing `window.onload` at all. Just declare the `initMap` function in the global scope.